# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in Character Counting in multiple textareas

Tags: javascript

I am coding a page to separately count characters in multiple textareas. The function works fine, but I am having the Error of 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null' while starting to type in the first textarea. The two questioned parts in console are highlighted below.

Can someone please help? How can this be fixed? Thank you very much!

[image]

```js
<script> 
  function textCounter(textField, showCountField, maxAmount,id) {
   if (textField.value.length <= maxAmount) {
    showCountField.value = maxAmount - textField.value.length;
    document.getElementById('go'+id).innerHTML  = '';
   } else { 
    document.getElementById('go'+id).innerHTML  = '<span style="color:red">Over!!</span>';
    textField.value = textField.value.substring(0,maxAmount);
   }
   }
</script>
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
   <textarea id="q" name="w" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.q,this.form.w,5,1);" onKeyPress="textCounter(this.form.q,this.form.w,5);"></textarea><br>
      <input type="text" name="w" value="5"></input>
   <p id="go1"/>
  </form><br>
  <form>
   <textarea id="a" name="s" onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.a,this.form.s,8,2);" onKeyPress="textCounter(this.form.a,this.form.s,8); "></textarea><br>
      <input type="text" name="s" value="8"></input>
   <p id="go2"/>
  </form><br>
  </body>
```

Comment: `getElementById('go'+id)` is apparently returning null. Make sure that `id` has the value you expect it to have, and make sure the document has an element matching that id.

Comment: Please post actual code, not an image. See [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you both! I am really new with learning coding. Could you please take a look at my HTML that I just edited in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listeners for `onKeyPress` are only passing 3 arguments to your `textCounter` function but it requires 4. The fourth argument, `id`, will be treated as undefined and the call to `document.getElementById` will be searching for an element with an id of `goundefined`.

Compare:

```
onKeyUp="textCounter(this.form.q,this.form.w,5,1);" 
onKeyPress="textCounter(this.form.q,this.form.w,5);"
```

Comment: Thank you for very much for pointing it out! Have it fixed now :)